# Android: Debugging shutdown receiver?

Tags: android, debugging

I have a receiver which is triggered at shutdown:

```
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverShutdown" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

when I set a breakpoint there for debugging I see eclipse stopping there, but the phone continues to shutdown. Hence I cannot debug my code (unless I can do it in less than 2s...). Is there any way of debugging this code? Apart from putting the code in an activity and debug it there, which is not always that easy.

Thanks,
A.

Comment: one other approach would be to log the events in a file and on starting the phone, you can check the file what happend... just the first thing that comes to my mind...

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug it.
If you want to test your code then you have to print on log-cat or you can save some values into preference.